# DevExpress XtraScheduler export to Outlook

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, scheduler

i wanna export my Appointments to Outlook. To accomplish this task iam using the method "Export to Outlook" on the SchedulerStorage.

```
myStorage.ExportToOutlook();
```

The problem is, that my Scheduler cant see, if this appointments are already included in Outlook. So if the user click export and after time he do again, he become all the appointments twice or more. I would need to update the avaiable appointments and insert the new appointments from my XtraScheduler in Outlook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should use the **synchronization** with MS Outlook instead of **exporting**.
You can read more about this technique here: [Synchronization with MS Outlook](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument3937)

By handling the synchronization events ([AppointmentSynchronizing](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/DevExpressXtraSchedulerExchangeAppointmentSynchronizer_AppointmentSynchronizingtopic), [AppointmentSynchronized](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/DevExpressXtraSchedulerExchangeAppointmentSynchronizer_AppointmentSynchronizedtopic)) and analizing their arguments (Operation value and Appointment parameter) you can implement any appointment conflict resolution scenario, while synchronizing scheduler storage with MS Outlook.

Comment: The AppointmentSynchronizeing and AppoinementSynchronized events are not fired after exporter.Synchronize()?

Comment: I always get an ArgumentException '' is not a valid value for 'columnName'. Can u help me? It is on Synchronize() Methode from exporter.